# Displays the black screen just before the video is loaded

Tags: swift

I have 1 AVPlayerViewController and AVPlayer I added the video to it and it worked. But when starting to load video there is a problem that a black screen appears for about 0.5s then the new video can start. I have added AVPlayerViewController to a UIView. I have looked at the background for the UIView medium with the color of the video but every time it loads it displays a black screen then it can start the video. can someone help me. this is my code

---

```
class WalkViewController: UIViewController{
@IBOutlet weak var view_player: UIView!
var avPlayer: AVPlayer!
    let avPlayerController = AVPlayerViewController()
    var sourc_video : String!
    var filepath: String!
    var fileURL: NSURL!

override func viewDidLoad() {
//video view payer
        self.filepath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(arr_video[0], ofType: "mp4")
        self.fileURL = NSURL.init(fileURLWithPath:filepath!)
        self.avPlayer = AVPlayer(URL: fileURL)
        self.avPlayerController.player = avPlayer
        self.avPlayerController.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 316, height: 316)
        self.avPlayerController.showsPlaybackControls = false
         self.avPlayerController.player?.play()
        avPlayerController.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
        self.addChildViewController(avPlayerController)
        self.view_player.addSubview(avPlayerController.view)
}
  override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your code is wrong. You must call `didMoveToParentViewController` after putting a child view controller’s view into the interface.

Second, video takes time to prepare. Put the view into the interface but hide it.  Use KVO to observe `isReadyForDisplay`. When it becomes true, now show the view.

Comment: Example code here: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch15p660EmbeddedAVKit/EmbeddedAVKit/ViewController.swift (case 2).